# Can't Open Eclipse "No Java virtual machine was found"

Tags: java, eclipse

I've checked the other relative common posts to mine but they a slight difference that didn't give me the solution I needed:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.  No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.80_25\jre\bin\javaw.exe

I have checked over and over in that path, and javaw.exe is definitely there.  Any ideas what to do, I had a exit-13 problem before I followed a step to add 
"-vm "path to javaw.exe" in my eclipse.ini but I don't know what to do now.

My eclipse.ini file:

```
    -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: haven't tested, but can you try to replace the backslashes with normal slashes? so it becomes sth like C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/javaw.exe

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work, uninstalled all my Java's, reinstalled jdk (x86) in my case, installed newest jre (x64) to delete obsolete ones from the jdk and it worked.  THanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\javaw.exe
```

should be something like

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/
```

or even better:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

On a side note, download the 64bit version if you can

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this file:
C:/Program Files/Java/jre(5,6,7...whatever version)/bin/javaw.exe
to the Eclipse folder (directory where the eclipse.exe is located)
Please note: Only tested for Windows

Answer (score 0):

The potential problem is you are using 64 bit Eclipse but 32 bit java. Either use 32 bit eclipse or install 64 bit java and re-try. It all started with Java 7!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, right click on Eclipse icon, select **Properties** and edit **Target** field.

There will be a large string, edit it to point to correct javaw.exe path:

```
-vm "c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javaw.exe"
```